# tinyMCE autoresize problem

Tags: tinymce

http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/5765/45696158.jpg
Having problem with tinyMCE's autoresize plugin... Is this correct behaviour or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a specified height and width to use, the autoresize plugin will decrease the height of the element. (it is increased as you type)

With a height specified, the initial display should keep that height.

Without seeing your code, it is hard to give more information.

Answer (score 1):

Like Rob said you need to specify the start height.

Like this:

```
tinyMceInit: function() {
    $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
         ....

         width : 600,
         **height : 90,**
         theme_advanced_resizing_min_height : 90,
         theme_advanced_resizing_max_height : 180,

         ....
    });
},
```

If you got resizing enabled you can limit it with max and min height!